# Sharing .org file between two users

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, files, org-capture

My secretory creates a daily agenda for me by capturing task to shared org file mytodo.org. When I open the agenda or mark the task done, her ability to capture new task gets limited as the mytodo.org gets locked. Or she gets a message : file is modified on disk. Would you like to continue?

How this can be tackled ?

Kindly help

Comment: Welcome! Not an answer proper, but this feature is documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking